# how to pass variable inside replace java-script function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, variables

I'm using the below code to trim the string based on the condition like 15 characters per line, in this below code, 15 was hard-coded.But I need to make it dynamic like defining variable and pass into replace function.

```
var str = "Here's to your next step.Keep Walking.Keep Watching"
result = str.replace(/(.{1,15})(?:\n|$| )/g, "$1|\n");
console.log(result);
```

**How I need**

```
var trim_val =15;
var str = "Here's to your next step.Keep Walking.Keep Watching"
result = str.replace(/(.{1,trim_val})(?:\n|$| )/g, "$1|\n"); //here i have to pass that variable
console.log(result);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: lookup `new RegExp` in the MDN documentation

Comment: `RegExp('(.{1,' + trim_val + '})(?:\\n|$| )', 'g')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the **[`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)**, to create a new Regex instance with your `trim_val` variable and use it in your `replace()` call.

This is how should be your code:

```
var trim_val = 15;
var str = "Here's to your next step.Keep Walking.Keep Watching";
var reg = new RegExp("(.{1,"+trim_val+"})(?:\n|$| )", "g");
var result = str.replace(reg, "$1|\n");
```

**Demo:**

```js
var trim_val = 15;
var str = "Here's to your next step.Keep Walking.Keep Watching";
var reg = new RegExp("(.{1,"+trim_val+"})(?:\n|$| )", 'g');
var result = str.replace(reg, "$1|\n"); //here i have to pass that variable
console.log(result);
```

Comment: it was worked..thanks a lot chsdk

Comment: @seshadry You are welcome, glad it helps.